# Как найти функцию к которой сходится сумма ряда?

Tags: математика, ряды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дана такая сумма ряда. Можете пожалуйста подсказать, как найти функцию, к которой она сходится (именно функцию)?

a-просто коэффициент.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Понятие "сходится" имело бы смысл при `m`, равном бесконечности; так это просто конечная сумма, которая равна

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откровенно - считал не сам, воспользовался книгой

Прудников А.П., Брычков Ю.А., Маричев О.И. *Интегралы и ряды*, М.:"Наука", 1981.
Ряд 4.4.1.5 на стр. 637.

То же самое можно получить, например, в Wolfram Mathematica :)

Comment: Спасибо большое! И за книгу тоже!

Comment: Вообще-то, это только первый том трехтомника :) https://ibb.co/rHQTWvv

Comment: Посчитать можно через сумму геометрической прогрессии с исп. формулы Эйлера (да, громоздко, но в школе заставляли)

Comment: @MBo Логично, мысль, даже не пришедшая в голову. Заодно и сумму косинусов посчитаем :) Спасибо!

Comment: Сори, вроде нажимал на "птичку", но не нажалась...